# Content blocks on dedicated pages rather than listed on one page

Tags: seo, web-development, mobile, accessibility

I am doing a web site for a client. The descriptions for all his services are rather short and precise so I decided to put them all (about 10 of them) on one page and have a sticky menu in the sidebar for quick access to each of the services. I find that a very usable experience. And for mobile (through the responsive approach), swiping through the services is more convenient than navigating to each service on a dedicated page.

But now an SEO guy comes in and tells me to put all services on dedicated pages, and the client then also has to transform all the about 60 words descriptions into 400 word descriptions, because Google demands 400 words to be on a page to be a page.

I my opinion this is a major step back in regard of accessibility/usability. And stuffing the descriptions with 'nonsense' just for the sake of the presumed SEO advantages? I really don't think so.

I am about to tell the client, that the SEO guy might not be right about that situation, but I am not sure, so who is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, i am not completely agree with your SEO guy to put 400 words of content by creating separate page for each service but i am agree with him on not to create just one page that contains all services !!

See, what i suggest is: create one page as you think to place all services there title and small description (2-3 lines) and put read more... link there. When someone click on read more.. link, they will go to detailed page of that service.

About service page; i recommend creating attractive landing page with call to action stuff rather than placing 400 words of content has no meaning.

I am sure it will solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I might consider the 'read more'-links but the descriptions now are already just 2-3 lines. Adding text would just create more content on separate pages. It's a dentist, so the services are more like 'this is part of my repertoire' rather than 'subscribe to this or buy that item'. Would you sill advise making a landing page and separate pages?

Comment: Yes, i will still advice to create service specific page as there are different types of expertise he may have. For example, Teeth Whitening, Root canal, Dental Implant, Dental cosmetic and so on..Let me know if you still need more information.